# Weird output with document.links.length

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Save the following in a file (eg. file.htm) and it works => prints out "3".
But if I uncomment the line 'document.write("Hello: ");' it doesn't work anymore (prints out "0"). Anyone knows why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function display() {
    //document.write("Hello: ");
    document.write(document.links.length + "<br>");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="display()">

<A href="link0.htm">Link 0</A>
<A href="link1.htm">Link 1</A>
<A href="link2.htm">Link 2</A>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Chrome I observe this behaviour, and most other browsers probably too. The reason is as follows:

Without the first `document.write`, it works as expected. Nothing special here.

But when you include the first `document.write` it overwrites the entire contents of the document, so then there aren't any links left. The second `document.write` reports correctly that there are 0 links in the document.

Comment: Was typing this actually! Good job

Comment: Pretty much, don't use document.write. Ever.

Comment: I tried it in IE, Firefox and Chrome. I think u are correct and ur explanation is very clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use document.write() to "display" your output. If this is just a test, use the alert() method. document.write() is only supposed to be used while the page is loading. Once the stream is closed and the document is loaded, document.write() will have unpredictable results.

Second, instead of using document.links, try using document.getElementsByTagName("A"). That will give you an array of all the anchor tags in the document.

Comment: It may be useful for other tags, but how do I count the num of tags with "___" in a document?

Comment: You didn't ask that question. You asked about links (<a></a>), otherwise known as "anchor" tags, and your example showed exactly those tags and nothing more.

Comment: My example exactly counts the number of anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call `document.write` the first time, it removes all links from the DOM.  It replaces the entire innerHTML of `document.body` with "Hello: ".

You should never use `document.write` anyway.